# App Store: app is released and showing on 9/10 devices, but not all

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios11.4, iphone7plus

The device that can't display the app is running version 11.4.1 (15G77). Instead of showing any apps, it's instead displaying 'no apps found'. Hoping someone has had a similar issue and found a fix.

Tried with different sets of iOS devices, none had the same issue.

Comment: make sure the app is available in that specific device App Store country

Comment: Hi Gustavo, it's available in the device's country.

Comment: did the app fall into a sensible category such as gambling?

Comment: Please provide more information, i.e. when was it publishing, is it a new app / update, deployment target, category etc. Where do you see the "no apps found"